# how to use FreeMarker template to generate outputs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, templates, gradle, freemarker

I am a python developer who knows itsy-bitsy Java. Now I am given some input data, in XML format, and a piece of template.ftl code. How can I "render" the input data in the template and generate the outputs? I suppose I will need to build a mar file which can consume the XML input data, right? Can someone give me some high level instructions? If there's an existing Github repo that I can reference to, that will be even better. Thanks!

Comment: From as much as I know from this, this is a quite basic use-case, so maybe be just look at the example in the official "Programmer's Guide": https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_quickstart_all.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [FMPP](https://fmpp.sourceforge.net/index.html) tool helped me to do exactly what I wanted to do.